# Read file from WEB-INF from any class

Tags: java, web-inf

How can I read a zip file from `WEBINF/` folder from a java class in a jar file in WEB-INF\eclipse\plugins folder? `classLoader.getResource(fileName)` works only if the file is inside the jar file in the `WEB-INF\eclipse\plugins` folder. I'd like to read it directly from application WEB-INF folder. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[javax.servlet.ServletContext.getResourceAsStream(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) exists for this purpose.